# mysql query for Library Management System

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table

member(memberNo, name, age),

book(isbn, title, author, publisher, year, category)

borrowed(memberNo, isbn, date)

and I am looking for answer or clue for the following query

**Find the names of members who have borrowed the same book more than once.**

I have been using the following but its giving me Just the column name 'name'

```
    SELECT member.name 
    FROM member 
    WHERE member.memberNo IN (SELECT borrowed.member_memberNo
    FROM borrowed 
    WHERE borrowed.book_isbn IN(
    SELECT COUNT(borrowed.book_isbn) as 'countNo' 
    FROM borrowed 
    WHERE 'countNo' >1));
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @Isaac Fife is correct - but I'm in a good mood and will give you some hints: search on GROUP BY and HAVING. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` to find the number of times a member has borrowed each book.

```
SELECT memberNo, isbn, COUNT(*) AS borrow_times
FROM borrowed
GROUP BY memberNo, isbn
```

Then check if `borrow_times > 1` to find the ones who have borrowed the same book more than once:

```
HAVING borrow_times > 1
```

Put this into a subquery so you can join it with the `member` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.name
FROM member AS m
JOIN (
    SELECT memberNo, isbn, COUNT(*) AS borrow_times
    FROM borrowed
    GROUP BY memberNo, isbn
    HAVING borrow_times > 1
) AS b ON m.memberNo = b.memberNo
```